# Excel: Copy and drag down for specific sheet structure

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a sheet with the structure seen in the image below. The original sheet however has **no** text in Column A (this is what I'd like to generate for my sheet).

I would like to drag down (or copy) the text in column C above each box (e.g., "'1234567-Name 1" in Box 1) so that it appears in Column A next to each row with text in within each box. What I am after is what appears in the image below.

How can I achieve this? Note that I have several boxes in my sheet but at least the distance between each box is always the same. Also the name above each box always starts with seven numerical characters. To make things more complicated the number of rows contained by each box may vary by a lot (1-300).

Thanks!

[image: What I am after]

Comment: Formula `A2 = IF(G2>4;A1;C1)` + conditional formatting `A2 format = IF(G2<=4; grey text by grey background)`? Maybe additionally check `IFERROR(G2>4)`

Comment: Since you have no Text in column A in original Sheet,, Then what is that base or where from you get it? Did you have store it anywhere or what?

Comment: If you have Text in Column A then the every first value since are duplicates can be copied in C using this `=INDEX(A$2:A$30,1,1)`.

Answer (score 0):

Type the following formula in cell `A6`:

```
=IF(LEN(B1)>3,C3,IF(LEN(B6)>0,A5,""))
```

and populate down.

Assumptions:

1) Text in cells `B1`, `B9` and so forth is at least 4 characters long (curently you have `yyyyyy`)

2) Numbers in Column `B` never exceeds `999` (or, to be more precise are never more than 3 characters long)